# React DevTools Open In Editor button disabled

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

A few days ago, I was working on a react project and open in editor was working fine, and now looking at it, the option is there but it is disabled. Not sure why, just all of a sudden the button is disabled. I tried updating the extension and deleting and installing it again but nothing has seemed to solve it.

[image: Screenshot]

It should have been enabled and take me to VS code showing me the exact file and line on that component being rendered from the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated you chrome recently? I've met the same problem, i guess that the chrome update caused the problem, try to use the lower version of chrome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).